# TypeError: 'TiffImageFile' object is not subscriptable for erose an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have the following code

```
url = 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/venus2.tif'
```

and the following code to read the image

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img


k=3
SE= np.ones((k,k), dtype=np.uint8)
constant= (k-1)//2


m,n = (img.size[0], img.size[1])
imgErode= np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.uint8)


#Erosion without using inbuilt cv2 function for morphology
for i in range(constant, m-constant):
  for j in range(constant,n-constant):
    temp= img[i-constant:i+constant+1, j-constant:j+constant+1]
    product= temp*SE
    imgErode[i,j]= np.min(product)

plt.imshow(imgErode,cmap="gray")
cv2.imwrite("Eroded3.png", imgErode)
```

and I get the following error

TypeError: 'TiffImageFile' object is not subscriptable

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show FULL error message and don't expect that we will run code to see it, and we can't read in your mind - so you may only suggest to use `print()`, `print(type())` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `'print debuging'`

Comment: `PIL` doesn't create `numpy array` but object `Image` - and this is your problem. If you would use `cv2` to read image then you would get `numpy array`. And now you have to convert object `Image` to `numpy array` - `img = np.asarray(img)` - but next you have to use `img.shape` instead of `img.size`

Answer (score 3):

`PIL` doesn't create `numpy.array` but object `PIL.Image` and you have to convert it

```
img = np.asarray(img)
```

Other problem:

After converting you have to use `img.shape` instead of `img.size` to get `height, width` because `img.size` in `numpy` gives number of bytes.

---

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

url = 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/venus2.tif'

response = requests.get(url)

img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
print('type:', type(img))

img = np.asarray(img)
print('type:', type(img))

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.waitKey(10)

k = 3
SE = np.ones((k, k), dtype=np.uint8)
constant = (k-1)//2

m, n = img.shape[0:2]
imgErode= np.zeros((m, n), dtype=np.uint8)

#Erosion without using inbuilt cv2 function for morphology
for i in range(constant, m-constant):
    for j in range(constant, n-constant):
        temp = img[i-constant:i+constant+1, j-constant:j+constant+1]
        product = temp * SE
        imgErode[i, j]= np.min(product)

cv2.imshow('converted', imgErode)
cv2.waitKey(10)

cv2.imwrite("Eroded3.png", imgErode)

#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Loading image from url using only `cv2`

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2

url = 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/venus2.tif'

response = requests.get(url)

arr = np.asarray(bytearray(response.content))#, dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.waitKey(100)
```

---

You may also use module [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) to read directly from url:

```
import imageio
import cv2

url = 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/venus2.tif'

img = imageio.imread(url)

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.waitKey(100)
```